# Запятая перед придаточным предложением.

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед придаточным предложением "независимо от того..."

Дееспособные коллективы(,) независимо оттого, персонал какой организации или предприятия они составляют, сколько вообще там работает сотрудников, опираются на несколько десятков ключевых специалистов, команду профессионалов.

Answer (score 2):

Независимо от_того...

Нет, ну это невозможно. Коряво же, мисс Алёнка... И потом – у вас смесь публицистического или даже научного стиля с разговорным, взгляните на "вообще" и вообще на построение фразы... Не нужна запятая...

Comment: А чем же коряво?

Comment: Корявости:
1. "Коллективы составляют персонал организации", а персонал делится на коллективы (лишняя банальная информация). 
2. "Сколько вообще" без в частности.
3. "Там работают". Где там? Ответ: организации или предприятия.
4. "Опираются на ключевых" (ключи не для того, чтобы на них опираться, а для того, чтобы ОТКРЫВАТЬ новые возможности).
5. "Коллективы опираются на команду профессионалов" (а сами коллективы - не профессионалы, с улицы зашли, и не команда, а толпа).

Comment: 6.Два критерия,которые не надо принимать во внимание, - какая организация и сколько у нее сотрудников. Что имеется в виду под "такая"? Полная размытость, а фактически критерий один: размер компании.

Comment: Мысль данного сообщения вполне понятна, несмотря на все "выявленные недостатки": дееспособность любого коллектива (любого размера, на любом предприятии) зависит от ключевых специалистов. (Именно этими специалистами следует дорожить, так как  они играют ключевую роль в реализации всех проектов, а остальные, которые "с улицы зашли", обычно являются просто исполнителями). А если мысль сразу ясна и понятна, то не так уж "коряво" она изложена. Мне показалось, что критический пафос разгромного разбора несколько несовместим с мелкими недостатками данного текста.

Comment: Ничего себе, вы шесть недостатков нашли в одной фразе – это всё мелкие? Но целых шесть в одном. Но мелких. )))

Comment: Я считаю, что надо подавать на апелляцию. Пять из шести, наверное, можно отсудить.

Comment: Мысль такая: Ядро дееспособного коллектива любой организации и предприятия, независимо от размера, составляют несколько десятков ключевых специалистов. Остальное - от лукавого.

Comment: Ну да, иногда писатель целый роман напишет, а "вдумчивый" читатель найдет в нем только одну мысль. А все остальное спишет на лукавого.

Comment: Я, как вдумчивый читатель, ТАКОЙ роман читать не буду. Уж извините.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагается вариант: "Дееспособные коллективы - независимо от того, персонал какой организации или предприятия они составляют, сколько вообще там работает сотрудников, - опираются на несколько десятков ключевых специалистов, команду профессионалов".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Здесь использована вставная конструкция, так как ее сложно встроить в предложение в связи с большой распространенностью. Также отнесение обособленной части на второй план речи обеспечит нормальное прочтение и понимание предложения .

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вариант действительно хороший, но если оставлять так, как есть, то, как я понимаю, раз вы выделили этот оборот, то запятая нужна...

Comment: Всю конструкцию в любом случае надо обособить, но грамматически это будет обособленное обстоятельство, включающее два придаточных предложения со своими знаками препинания, - соответственно, мы получаем  плохо читаемое предложение.